# C++ Semaphore and pthreads behaving indeterminately

Tags: c++, pthreads, osx-mavericks, semaphore

my professor has given us a code example to examine over the weekend. A code example which he says compiles and runs however I can't run it and reproduce the desired behavior. The program is supposed to run and print out a 1 on the first line and a 2 on the second line. Instead it behaves indeterminately sometimes putting 12 or 21 or even the desired output. What's going on here? I'm compiling on OSX mavericks.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

sem_t mySemaphore;

void *f1(void *param)
{
        cout << (long)param << std::endl;

        // signal semaphore
        // increment the value of mySemaphore by 1
        // if there are one or more threads waiting, wake
        sem_post(&mySemaphore);

        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *f2(void *param)
{
        // wait until value of semaphore is greater than 0
        // decrement the value of semaphore by 1
        sem_wait(&mySemaphore);

        cout << (long)param << std::endl;

        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
        pthread_t myThread[2];

        // The 3rd value which is semaphore count set to 0
        sem_init(&mySemaphore, 0, 0);

        long one = 1, two = 2;

        // f2 has sem_wait(), so it should wait
        // until f1 increase the semaphore value to 1
        // As a result, f1 will be executed first
        pthread_create(&myThread[0], 0, f1, (void *)one);
        pthread_create(&myThread[1], 0, f2, (void *)two);

        pthread_join(myThread[0], 0);
        pthread_join(myThread[1], 0);
        sem_destroy(&mySemaphore);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your analysis of the program? How do you think it should behave? In what way does it behave differently? Show some effort!

Comment: Figured it out. The compiler on OSX Mavericks using doesn't support semaphores it seems. If I compile it on an old Redhat vm I've got it works fine. Would have never thought to check for unsuportted features in a language or library I guess that just comes with the C++ territory. Thanks for you help /s

Comment: Now that you found that out, we can even find the duplicates ;) http://stackoverflow.com/q/23409996