# Semaphores in C++

Tags: c++, semaphore

I'm having some very basic trouble with semaphores.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <semaphore.h>
int main() {
  sem_t sem;
  sem_init(&sem, 1, 1);
  sem_wait(&sem);
  sem_wait(&sem);
  printf("Return value: %d\n", sem_wait(&sem));
  return 0;
}
```

I expect this code to wait forever (due to the second sem_wait).
Instead, it prints out "Return value: -1", and exits.
I am compiling with g++ version 4.2.1 on a Mac (OSX 10.8.5).

Comment: Your code works on my computer. Ubuntu 12.04 64bit with kernel 3.2.0, libc-2.15

Comment: This post says that OS/X doesn't support unnamed POSIX semaphores: http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-kernel/2009/Apr/msg00010.html

Comment: So I should use sem_open() instead of sem_init()?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409996/pthread-and-semaphore-not-working-for-me-in-osx-maverick-10-9) post says yes, you should use sem_open instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS/X does not support unnamed POSIX semaphores.  Use sem_open() instead of sem_init().